# SVN re-checkout (switch/relocate/something else?)

Tags: svn, repository

The project that I am currently working on at the moment uses SVN for version control. When it was initially created (by another person who is not currently available), the 'public_html' folder on the server was checked out to the following folder: https://URL/project_name/ with 'project_name' being the root of the repository. It did not provide any structure for branches/tags because apparently it didn't look like we would ever need it.

Now that we realise that we need the branches to organise parallel work on several versions of the project, we decided to create a new repository with proper structure ( URL/project_name/trunk/ for the main version and URL/project_name/branches/... for secondary ones). There is no problem with organising the repository itself, but how do I do a new checkout for the 'public_html' folder on the server? If I try to do 'svn checkout URL/project_name/trunk /home/public_html', I get the error message saying that 'public_html' is already a working copy for a different URL.

I tried to look at the svn switch and svn relocate options on a local test machine through Tortoise SVN, but the former only seems to work for switching among branches of the same repository, and the latter requires to specify the root of the repository (and I need to specify the URL/project_name/trunk as checkout folder). Could anyone help or at least direct me in this situation?

I do have a root SSH access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TortoiseSVN Help](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html):

> Put another way, you need to relocate when your working copy is
>   referring to the same location in the same repository, but the
>   repository itself has moved.
>
> It does not apply if:
>
> You want to move to a different Subversion repository. In that case
>   you should perform a clean checkout from the new repository location.
>
> You want to switch to a different branch or directory within the same
>   repository. To do that you should use TortoiseSVN → Switch.... Read
>   Section 4.19.2, “To Checkout or to Switch...” for more information.

So, what you must do is checkout a new fresh copy. Either Delete the whole content of your directory and then checkout, or Checkout to a new directory, and then rename the new one with the name of the old one.

Comment: Checkout a new fresh copy sounds like what I tried to do. How should I delete the content in the 'public_html' directory?

Comment: Select all the content in your windows explorer with Ctrl-A, and press the Delete key of your keyboard.

Comment: As soon as the '.svn' is gone from 'public_html', I should be able to do a fresh checkout, right?

Comment: If you don't use the latest SVN version, you'll have a .svn in every subdirectory as well. And SVN will download all the files from the repository anyway and (IIRC) overwrite existing files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to svn move your project_name to your trunk. Do not alter directly your file system ; it will have no effect on your repo files. Use **svn commands** instead.

```
// in URL (parent folder of project_name)
svn mkdir trunk
svn mkdir branches
svn mkdir tags
svn move project_name trunk 
svn ci -m 'moved'
```

et voilà

if you don't have a parent folder, you will have to "svn move" every file and directory in the project_name root one by one.

Comment: Great! This actually feels like a natural way to tackle this problem. And yeah, we do not have a parent folder, so I guess there will be some manual work. I guess that when this is done, in order to make my 'public_html' directory to refer to the trunk folder, I can just use 'svn switch /home/public_html/ URL/project_name/trunk' ?

Comment: Yes i forgot the switch option ; so your local copy will point to the trunk

Answer (score 1):

If `project_name` is your root folder you can create the branches/tags/trunk structure under it and do a manually `svn move` for each file/folder contained in `project_name` (except branches/tags/trunk of course). So you can preserve all the history of your commits. It's tedious, but safe!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a GUI to SVN like TortoiseSVN??? 
I think that relocating stuff in the repo was as easy as dragging with the right click and selecting the appropriate option and then commit.

Also you can try to do it within the repo-browser.
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html